# Restricting php functions executed on the command line

Tags: php

Now normally I would never allow things like this in an application for obvious reasons, but for this application I am writing, I want to be able to execute user added php on the command line. However, I want to restrict/remove certain functions, e.g. file system functions, db functions, `shell_exec` etc. I will be running PHP >5.4, and using a custom `php.ini` is possible if it helps.

I essentially need to remove the possibility of a user doing anything harmful with their code.

I can control which user runs the php scripts, so I can use `user:group` combinations to restrict access to certain files.

It will be possible to regex their code well before executing and reject it completely.

Can anyone suggest options for doing this?

Comment: PHPs [Tokenizer](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tokenizer.php) is your friend.

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER That is a great suggestion, I will look into that. If someone was to build a function name from a string, would the Tokenizer pick that up? If not I guess I could potentially look for function calls from a variable function name

Comment: The only way you can call functions without call them directly as a function is using one of the `call_user_func_array()` like functions afaik. So you have to check the parameters of them against unallowed method names.

Comment: I was thinking about something like $fn = 'my' . 'sql_connect'; $fn();

Comment: According my example in the updated answer below it gets difficult to find this out. But I think it's possible.

Comment: That's a great example, and definitely gives me something to work with. Thanks very much for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PHPs built-in [Tokenizer](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tokenizer.php) to parse users PHP script and check against unallowed method calls.

A short sample script which will give you an idea what I'm talking about:

```
$str = "<?php

\$fp = fopen('test.txt', 'wb');

call_user_func_array('fopen', array('test.txt', 'wb'));

\$file = new File;

\$fn = 'my' . 'sql_connect';
\$fn();

echo 'hello world';";

$tokenizedPhp = token_get_all($str);

$i = -1;
foreach($tokenizedPhp as $token) {
    ++$i;

    if(is_array($token) === false) {
        echo $i , ': punctuation -> ' , $token , PHP_EOL;
        continue;
    }

    echo $i , ': ' , token_name($token[0]) , ' -> ' , $token[1] , PHP_EOL;

    if($token[0] === T_STRING && function_exists($token[1]))
        echo '<b>function call/class instanciation: ' , $token[1] , '</b>' , PHP_EOL;
}
```